# Consolidating repeating information

Tags: sql

The problem is that the WO: W142930 Leg 0 repeats multiple times, this creates too much of a mess.
I can clean this up with a pivot table in excel, but I would much rather learn how to do it in SQL.
I don’t know if it is possible but I would like to see the total “ACT_RUN_HRS” shown at the top of every leg.

The code that I wrote:

```
select
w.base_id as WO_ID
, w.sub_id as LEG
, w.desired_qty as WO_QTY
, OPR.ACT_RUN_HRS
, OPR.ACT_SETUP_HRS
, cast ((OPR.ACT_RUN_HRS + OPR.ACT_SETUP_HRS) AS decimal(15,4)) AS TOTAL_RUN_HOURS
, cast(w.close_date as date) AS CLOSE_DATE
, cast(cast( wb.bits as varbinary(100)) as varchar(100)) as SPEC
from work_order w
left join workorder_binary wb on
w.type = wb.workorder_type and
w.base_id = wb.workorder_base_id and
w.lot_id = wb.workorder_lot_id and
w.split_id = wb.workorder_split_id and
w.sub_id = wb.workorder_sub_id
left join operation opr
ON w.type = opr.workorder_type and
w.base_id = opr.workorder_base_id and
w.lot_id = opr.workorder_lot_id and
w.split_id = opr.workorder_split_id and
w.sub_id = opr.workorder_sub_id
left join PART p0 on p0.id = w.PART_ID and '0' = w.SUB_ID
left join CUSTOMER c on c.id = p0.user_1
WHERE year(w.CLOSE_DATE) >= 2017
and year(w.CLOSE_DATE) <= 2018
and w.STATUS='C'
and w.TYPE = 'W'
and w.BASE_ID LIKE 'W%'
and w.BASE_ID = 'w142930'
Order by w.base_id, w.sub_id
```

[image: Current SQL Output]
[image: Needed SQL Output]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

I've updated my answer to replace each of the fields (`w.base_id`, `w.sub_id`, `w.desired_qty`, and `wb.bits`) with a cast to varchar(100), and I've amended the GROUP BY clause to include the same cast. Let me know if this works for you.

### Update 2

I replaced `cast(wb.bits as varchar(100))` with `cast(cast(wb.bits as varbinary(100)) as varchar(100))`

### Update 3

As @DeathMagnetic figured out, the `ORDER BY` columns must be present in either the `SELECT` or `GROUP BY` clause

### Answer

You're looking for `SUM()` and `GROUP BY`. Something like the following should work (I haven't tested this, though, as I don't have a database set up with your schema):

```
SELECT
    cast(w.base_id as varchar(100)) as WO_ID,
    cast(w.sub_id as varchar(100)) as LEG,
    cast(w.desired_qty as varchar(100)) as WO_QTY,
    SUM(OPR.ACT_RUN_HRS),
    SUM(OPR.ACT_SETUP_HRS),
    SUM(cast ((OPR.ACT_RUN_HRS + OPR.ACT_SETUP_HRS) AS decimal(15,4))) AS 
TOTAL_RUN_HOURS
    cast(w.close_date as date) AS CLOSE_DATE,
    cast(cast(wb.bits as varbinary(100)) as varchar(100)) as SPEC
FROM
    work_order w
LEFT JOIN
    workorder_binary wb ON
        w.type = wb.workorder_type and
        w.base_id = wb.workorder_base_id and
        w.lot_id = wb.workorder_lot_id and
        w.split_id = wb.workorder_split_id and
        w.sub_id = wb.workorder_sub_id
LEFT JOIN
    operation opr ON
        w.type = opr.workorder_type and
        w.base_id = opr.workorder_base_id and
        w.lot_id = opr.workorder_lot_id and
        w.split_id = opr.workorder_split_id and
        w.sub_id = opr.workorder_sub_id
LEFT JOIN
    PART p0 ON
        p0.id = w.PART_ID and
        '0' = w.SUB_ID
LEFT JOIN
    CUSTOMER c ON
        c.id = p0.user_1
WHERE
    year(w.CLOSE_DATE) >= 2017
    and year(w.CLOSE_DATE) <= 2018
    and w.STATUS = 'C'
    and w.TYPE = 'W'
    and w.BASE_ID LIKE 'W%'
    and w.BASE_ID = 'w142930'
GROUP BY
    cast(w.base_id as varchar(100)),
    cast(w.sub_id as varchar(100)),
    cast(w.desired_qty as varchar(100)),
    cast(w.close_date as date),
    cast(cast(wb.bits as varbinary(100)) as varchar(100))
ORDER BY
    cast(w.base_id as varchar(100)), cast(w.sub_id as varchar(100))
```

In general:

- When using aggregate functions (`COUNT`, `SUM`, `AVERAGE`, etc) every single column returned must **either** be an aggregate, or part of the `GROUP BY` clause. Suppose you only grouped by `w.base_id` and `w.sub_id`, and suppose you had two different values for `w.desired_qty` for the same `w.base_id` and `w.sub_id` -- which one would you want to return? For this reason, you would either need to group by `w.desired_qty` or use some aggregate function to tell it how to choose (`MAX`, `MIN`, etc)
- `WHERE` clauses execute before `GROUP BY` clauses, so it will only sum / average / aggregate the rows which are returned by your `WHERE`. If you want to further filter **based on these aggregates** (e.g., return all people with a `SUM(OPR.ACT_RUN_HOURS) > 10`) then you should use a `HAVING` clause (which functions a lot like a `WHERE` clause, but runs after the `GROUP BY` instead of before)

Comment: I have tried running the code. I get an error Msg.: 
Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Line 33
The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

The line that this is referring to is:
GROUP BY w.base_id, w.sub_id, w.desired_qty, w.close_date, wb.bits

Comment: @Ben I have tried to add select cast(w.base_id as NVARCHAR(100)) as WO_ID , cast(w.sub_id as NVARCHAR(100)) as LEG and GROUP BY cast(w.base_id AS NVARCHAR(100)), cast(w.sub_id AS NVARCHAR(100)) to everything and that did not work either.

Comment: @DeathMagnetic I've updated my post with a `cast` on both the select and group by clauses. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: This is the new error: Msg 529, Level 16, State 2, Line 46
Explicit conversion from data type image to nvarchar is not allowed.
This relates to cast(wb.bits as varchar(100)) under GROUP BY

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that you were casting to `varbinary(100)` before casting to `varchar(100)`. I'll update once more. Although if this is image data, do you need to return this in your query at all? What are you doing with this column that you need it?

Comment: I don't understand what "image data" means. In our ERP system, there is a field where the text is entered to describe the work order. This text is stored as a binary in the "workorder_binary" table. To convert it back from binary I had to use the formula `cast(cast(wb.bits as varbinary(100)) as varchar(100))`.

Comment: After you have modified the code, I came up with an error again: "Msg 8127, Level 16, State 1, Line 48
Column "work_order.BASE_ID" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." This is referring to `ORDER BY w.base_id, w.sub_id` based on everything that you have done, I was able to figure out that it needed to be: `ORDER BY
    cast(w.base_id as varchar(100)), cast(w.sub_id as varchar(100))` after that modification, I got the result that i was looking for! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @DeathMagnetic Great job figuring it out :) And glad I could help. I'll update my answer with your correction

Answer (score 0):

You want use what are called Aggregate functions along with a `GROUP BY` clause. It pretty much works how it sounds. I'm sure you can google for more information to learn about them, but for your specific question you can `SUM` the values you want, grouped by the values that you want to sum over. Something like:

```
select
w.base_id as WO_ID
, w.sub_id as LEG
, w.desired_qty as WO_QTY
, SUM(OPR.ACT_RUN_HRS) AS SUM_ACT_RUN_HRS
, SUM(OPR.ACT_SETUP_HRS) AS SUM_ACT_SETUP_HRS
, SUM(cast ((OPR.ACT_RUN_HRS + OPR.ACT_SETUP_HRS) AS decimal(15,4))) AS 
TOTAL_RUN_HOURS
, cast(w.close_date as date) AS CLOSE_DATE
, cast(cast( wb.bits as varbinary(100)) as varchar(100)) as SPEC
from work_order w
left join workorder_binary wb on
w.type = wb.workorder_type and
w.base_id = wb.workorder_base_id and
w.lot_id = wb.workorder_lot_id and
w.split_id = wb.workorder_split_id and
w.sub_id = wb.workorder_sub_id
left join operation opr
ON w.type = opr.workorder_type and
w.base_id = opr.workorder_base_id and
w.lot_id = opr.workorder_lot_id and
w.split_id = opr.workorder_split_id and
w.sub_id = opr.workorder_sub_id
left join PART p0 on p0.id = w.PART_ID and '0' = w.SUB_ID
left join CUSTOMER c on c.id = p0.user_1
WHERE year(w.CLOSE_DATE) >= 2017
and year(w.CLOSE_DATE) <= 2018
and w.STATUS='C'
and w.TYPE = 'W'
and w.BASE_ID LIKE 'W%'
and w.BASE_ID = 'w142930'
GROUP BY w.base_id, w.sub_id, w.desired_qty, w.close_Date, wb.bits
Order by w.base_id, w.sub_id
```

Should do what you want. You may need to include the casting from the selects in the group by columns to get the exact result you're after, but I don't think so.